# Drawing Sketch Video Tutorial on Titanic Ship

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, drawing

YouTube Video URL :

https://youtu.be/aZI1LO8AxAA

This is a tutorial on Drawing Titanic Ship free hand sketch.

I would like to know using drawing tools viz Adobe Photoshop, MSPaint etc whether the Titanic ship can be drawn as effectively as shown in the video.[image][image]

Comment: Sure, you can mimic that style digitally using a drawing tablet and just about any capable application with good customizable brushes: Photoshop, Corel Painter, Autodesk Sketchbook Pro, Medibang Paint, Clip Studio Paint, Krita... Or even some applications on tablet computers, like Procreate... but you do need just about the same amount of practice if not more... So if you were thinking of getting ahead doing it digitally, that won't happen. If you can do it digitally, you can do it on paper. And don't even think about using a mouse or I'm coming for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With enough skill, patience, and practice just about anything drawn with analog tools can be created digitally. Some things merely take *way* more practice and experience.

One *can* mimic the appearance of a charcoal drawing using digital tools. *Which* digital tools to use is your choice and ultimately a matter of preference and feature sets.

Comment: Thanks. Added are Digital Tablet devices images. Should i purchase a Digital Tablet for my Son? A Digital Tablet is better than a Mouse input device & MS paint software application?

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar - there are already lots of questions here on GDSE about graphics tablets, their benefits and uses. Maybe check them out by searching this site.  However if you want to draw thick and thin, heavy or light strokes, then a tablet and pressure sensitive stylus is a must. A mouse won't cut it.

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar, for a beginner... I might look at Huion drawing tablets first. Wacom I think usually bundles in some software for drawing, but there is also free software like Krita, which is at least better than MS paint.

Comment: Digital drawing is a very per-user thing. As an example I have decades of experience, a good computer system, several tablets (iPads) and a few drawing tablets (Wacom)... I *still* **much prefer** a pen and a piece of paper to draw as *least* a key line. I will then scan and use software to refine. This is just how I work. I do not often enjoy drawing from scratch digitally. Although I can, it's never my "go-to" method.

Comment: Thanks Scott for the information provided.

Comment: Happy to help @PrashantAkerkar If money ins't an object then the only *real* way you'll know if your son likes drawing digitally is to get a tablet with a pressure sensitive stylus. And he'll need to use it for at least a couple weeks to get acclimated to it. Only then can it really be evaluated effectively. But I agree with others, a mouse, trackpad, trackball, et. al. will only present more hurdles than benefits.

Comment: If Money is an concern, I'd suggest a used or refurbished tablet on the cheaper side until he's certain he likes it. I'd be inclined to start with something like an iPad and some free drawing software. That way the device will have other uses beyond merely drawing. The overall "feel" is somewhat similar between a tablet device and a digitizing tablet (Wacom). For me, the loss of all tactile expression with digital drawing is unpleasant - regardless of the device/software being used. But there are thousands, if not millions, of users that don't find that problematic.

Comment: @Scott - yeah the lack of a tactile feel is an issue for me too. Wonder if you've seen the [Wacom Pro Paper Edition](https://estore.wacom.com/en-GB/wacom-intuos-pro-paper-medium-m-en-fr-es-it-nl-pth-660p-s.html). Looks very interesting. I'll have to investigate more.

Comment: @BillyKerr, man... I am definitely on the opposite side on this one. I hate that paper like texture trend so much. It serves no purpose other than to destroy the pen tips 100 times faster. Like the pretty durable gray nibs with the spring can last years on a smooth surface but on a paper like surface you can flatten it in like two days. I've even gone as far as putting plastic screen portectors for tablet computers on top of the textured surface... I do also like when it glides easily, like especially the ones with a glass display.

Comment: @joonas - yeah, wear on a nib could be a problem, however the wacom paper edition appears to actually use a wacom pen that has ink in it, like a traditional pen nib. So it might not be such an issue since the pen is designed to be used on paper, unlike a normal wacom stylus. All very interesting though.

Comment: @BillyKerr, I haven't tried any of the ink pens, but that combination always felt clumsy to me. Like do you look at the paper or the screen and whats the benefit? ...but I do have Wacom's discontinued Inkling pen, which is kind of the same thing in a portable format. I thought it was a cool idea at the time but maybe a bit cumbersome when you can always take a photo to digitise the drawing. By the way I guess the successor of Inkling is Bamboo Slate and Bamboo Folio. I think  they're both more aimed towards note taking, but I did see a review where it looked to work pretty ok for drawing.

Comment: @Joonas - You look at the paper, and draw as you would normally with a pen.  There's an unboxing+review on youtube here that kinda describes how it works. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOOgPUEiBDo&ab_channel=Jazza

Comment: @BillyKerr, it makes more sense now looking at the video... Wacom has had an ink pen for a long time, like 15 years or so? So I just kinda assumed it works like those did... Basically just like any drawing tablet but you drew on paper at the same time, but what this does is basically the same as Bamboo Slate or Inkling, but it has the computer connected drawing tablet functionality as well. I could see people who prefer to work with ink pens using this... Maybe... I'd jump straight to one with a display.

Comment: @Joonas I directly complained to Wacon about the textured surface when I got my last Intuos Pro (ermm... 15 years ago?) Thankfully, the surface has been worn smooth over time. But I agree, the textured surfaces merely serve to chew down nibs 10x faster. And get this.. to replace the surface it's a REPAIR you can't merely buy sheets for the surface. They followed Adobe into the "to hell with the customer we need money" method of sales.

Comment: @BillyKerr you can get one of the "inking stylii" from Wacom and just put a piece of paper on any of their tablets. At least you used to be able to do that. Not sure if they still sell the inking stylus though.

Comment: All.. I have a Wacom Inkling... little bar and pen to draw and the bar reads what you draw.. it's a nifty gadget.... introducing a new type of frustration... but hey.. you can merely scan the drawing you made and trace it :) Note it DOES work, but it requires some odd hand/wrist/arm angles at times and there's little way to know when it's NOT being accurate until you load it into a system and realize you just wasted an hour for worthless scribbles.